# Raspberry Pi 3 model B wifi monitor mode

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Q. Has anyone managed to configure a raspberry-pi 3 b for monitor-mode?

- I have an external (Edimax) WiFi USB dongle also, which works with my PC in monitor mode but does not work with the raspberry pi.
- I know about the [nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) project and [the limitations of the builtin broadcom chips regarding not being able to work in monitor mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=222151).
- I already tried the [re4son kernel](https://re4son-kernel.com/re4son-pi-kernel/) also. The re4son kernel once installed does not let the raspberrypi boot up cleanly. Some errors about not being able to configure network time.
- I am unable to compile the nexmon patch because of a missing dependency ([libmpfr4](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/#download)). I downloaded the source for that library, but strangely it compiles to libmpfr6 and not libmpfr4 (even though the download source package is named mpfr4.0.2. I mean who came up with that numbering scheme?)
- I downloaded [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) that is [needed to build modules](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219049) and tried also downloading and compiling two driver versions for the Edimax Dongle - the [rtl8192cu](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) driver version and the [rtl7611](https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000047172-how-to-install-ew-7611ulb-adapter-on-raspberry-pi) driver and I thought that I could compile the driver and load into the kernel.
- Unfortunately the rtl7611 driver version just does not compile because of the [changes in the kernel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565381/what-is-alternative-of-create-proc-entry) and [here](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/241), I guess.
- The RTL8192cu compiled and as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes), I blacklisted the builtin 8192cu driver and installed the compiled driver. Rebooted and was expecting to be able to put the external wifi dongle into monitor mode, but alas. It wouldn't go into monitor mode still.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
iwconfig
```

Comment: Just an update for anyone who stumbles upon this post. I just bought a different USB-Wifi Dongle, which works fine out-of-the-box with the Raspberry pi. I can put it in monitor mode and it works.